# What's the term to mean brown something?

Tags: single-word-requests

I always thought it was **caramelize** but then today I read this somewhere

> Onions require 30 to 45 minutes of cooking to caramelize

But what if I just wanted to brown something and not overcook it.

For example, what if I sauté chopped onions for 5 to 10 minutes and they get all browned? What's the exact word to represent that?

**Note**: I am not interested in onions per se, but the word to represent "brown".

**[Notes from comments:]**

1. I'm least interested in the cooking part here. I want an accurate English word to substitute for "brown" as a verb.
2. Is there a legitimate single-word substitute?

Comment: This is asking for cooking advice :) well... *nearly*. Actually... it is [Seasoned advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) To soften the onions is usually called sauteing, while caramelizing turns the onion slices a *golden brown*. Brown onions sounds like they've been cooked too long, or over a high flame.

Comment: No @Mari-LouA it's related to English. I m least interested in the cooking part here. I want an accurate English word to substitute for "brown" as a verb.

Comment: So what do you mean by *browning* something. It's still cooking, right? You can brown the meat, but normally I'd say, "cook/roast/fry/grill until well done/crispy/nearly burnt at the edges) Results for: [**to brown meat**](https://www.google.it/search?q=brown+the+meat&oq=brown+the+meat&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22+to+brown+meat%22&tbm=bks&start=10)

Comment: So there's no other legitimate single-word substitute?

Comment: To *brown* is a single-word! To *umber* is another, but I'd never use it for cooking, and it's a pretty unusual word. The verb *to embrown* is more common, and perhaps it was the elder sibling of "to brown"

Comment: Sorry to break this to you, but the word is "brown".  "Caramalize" is used for some foods, such as onions, but not, eg, for most meats.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The OED provides three meanings for the verb *brown* - one of which means to fire a gun indiscriminately. But of the examples given only two refer to cooking, one from 1769 and one from 1859.

Comment: @MamtaD "cook until they get a nice brownish color" or "until they get golden brown" is what people usually say... http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/french-english/dorer

Comment: @HotLicks - You got it right. The word is [_brown_](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22brown+the+*+over+a+low+heat%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Comment: (BTW, I'm not much of a cook but I've watched enough cooking shows to know that, with regard to onions, there's a broad range of opinions as to what "caramalize" or "brown" means -- some would do this only a minute or two in a hot skillet, others would "simmer" for 15 minutes (at a slightly lower temperature).  If it's important one should specify more precisely somehow.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to break this to you, but the word is "brown". "Caramalize" is used for some foods, such as onions, but not, eg, for most meats.

BTW, I'm not much of a cook but I've watched enough cooking shows to know that, with regard to onions, there's a broad range of opinions as to what "caramalize" or "brown" means -- some would do this only a minute or two in a hot skillet, others would "simmer" for 15 minutes (at a slightly lower temperature). If it's important one should specify more precisely somehow.

But with meats there's not as much variation.

Answer (score 4):

Other than 'to brown', there's

> umber (verb)
>
> trans. To stain or paint with umber; to make of a dark brown colour.

and also

> embrown (verb)
>
> To make brown. Also (rarely) intr. for refl.

(All definitions from [OED Online](http://oed.com/).)

---

### Culinary Note

'Caramelize', although frequently used, is usually used inaccurately with reference to the browning of onions, other vegetables, or meats. The more accurate term, which also accurately describes the browning of bread crust, is

> **maillardize**

which comes from the term 'Maillard Reaction':

> The Maillard reaction (pronounced "my-YARD") is a culinary phenomenon that occurs when proteins in meat are heated to temperatures of 310°F or higher, causing them to turn brown.

(From ["What is the Maillard Reaction?"](http://culinaryarts.about.com/od/glossary/g/maillard.htm) at [*About food*](http://www.about.com/food/).)

As noted at that source, however,

> ... while caramelization is not the identical chemical process as the Maillard reaction, only the most pedantic hairsplitter would actually take the trouble to correct you on it. Also simply referred to as "browning."

So, pedantically delving deeper into the 'maillardize'/'caramelize' distinction, with special reference to onions, this appears:

> ... how, exactly, do you caramelize onions?
>
> The short answer is "you don't." Strictly speaking, caramelization is what happens to sugars when exposed to relatively high heat. When you're browning onions, however you do it, you rarely reach the temperatures necessary for caramelization. The browning you see is, instead, caused primarily by the Maillard reaction (say "My-Yard" and you'll be close enough), which is the reaction between sugars or other carbohydrates and amino acids. Maillard flavors are more complex and "meaty" than caramelized flavors, which is why so-called caramelized onions are so flavorful.

(From ["How to Brown Onions"](http://cookingfortwo.about.com/od/techniques/a/Two-Ways-To-Brown-Onions.htm), op. cit.)

Comment: Those are interesting verbs, but I woudn't use them in recipes. Google found no hits for "umber the onions".

Comment: @J.R., when was the last time you cooked for Picasso? Nonetheless, I'm sure what your recipe vocabulary encompasses is completely pertinent.

Comment: I'm just trying to map the O.P.'s question to the verbs in your answer. Had the O.P. asked, "I am painting our living room a deep, rich brown – is there a word for that?" then I'd regard _umber_ as a fine choice. But when the O.P. asks for an "exact word" to mean, "sauté chopped onions for 5 to 10 minutes [until] they get all browned," then I'm not sure how well _umber_ fits in. It seems like **someone** should investigate to at least see if that verb is ever used when referring to sautéed onions – or sautéed anything. Since your answer didn't do that, I thought I'd add it as a footnote.

Comment: @J.R., understood, but your approach seems to neglect at least a couple of factors that played into my answer: "So there's no other legitimate single-word substitute?" was the OP's comment. That's one. Another is that recipes are fit places for creative vocabulary, so whether the word has been used in a recipe is not really restrictive, so long as it communicates. Myself, I'm growing fonder of "umber the onions" by the minute. To be sure, it's a stage beyond browning/caramelizing them, but not infrequently described as "caramelize to a deep brown". Then there's Stein's masquerade....

Comment: My comment begins with "Those are interesting verbs," which was meant to be complimentary. Moreover, I'm not saying you _couldn't_ use them in a recipe. Lest my remarks be misconstrued, I'm not against outside-the-box suggestions. However, when someone asks for an "exact word" at a site that aims to "build a library of detailed answers," I think a small caveat is in order. We should clarify: is this a word commonly used in the domain? Or are we blazing (simmering?) a trail?

Comment: @J.R., again, another OP comment: 'I m least interested in the cooking part here. I want an accurate English word to substitute for "brown" as a verb.' Perhaps those comments (or their substance) should be in the question, but faulting the answer for the question's deficiencies seems to be putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: Point of order: I haven't "faulted" anything. I only tried to improve the overall usefulness of this answer by adding a simple fact. As for writing an answer that addresses comments, there's some usefulness in that, I suppose, but what happens when a new user finds this question a year from now, and reads just the question, and then just your answer? If you're going to address comments in your answer, it's probably worth saying so in your answer (a lead-in like, "Since you've said in a comment that you're not merely interested in the cooking part..." would do the trick, I think).

Comment: @J.R., okay, I've 'improved' the answer.

Comment: And how! You've got my upvote. That's impressive.